# How do I add a comma after each character in a string using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I have a string with periods and numbers.

Ex.  4..1...68875....9.....92.7...42.9..6..9...1..6..7.59...8.64.....5....71494...3..2

I am trying to add a comma after each character to get this:

4,.,.,1,.,.,.,6,8,8,7,5,.,.,.,.,9,.,.,.,.,.,9,2,.,7,.,.,.,4,2,.,9,.,.,6,.,.,9,.,.,.,1,.,.,6,.,.,7,.,5,9,.,.,.,8,.,6,4,.,.,.,.,.,5,.,.,.,.,7,1,4,9,4,.,.,.,3,.,.,2

I have about 50 of these lines to convert.  Is there a quicker way to do so with AppleScript?

All the searches return how to split with delimiters but I have no idea what terminology I am looking at and what phrase I need to use to get the actual answer.

I just want to add a comma after each character.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where are these ~50 strings, in a file? If yes, and this it just something your trying to do and you though maybe AppleScript, well there are easier ways, `sed` as an example: `sed -e 's/./&,/g' -e 's/,$//' file > newfile`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set myVar to "4..1...68875....9.....92.7...42.9..6..9...1..6..7.59...8.64.....5....71494...3..2"

set {saveTID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, {""}}

set myList to text items of myVar as list

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {","}

set myString to myList as string

set AppleScript's text item delimiters to saveTID
```